# Get user API key automatically while endpoint returns HTTP 401

Tags: postman

Is there a way in Postman to obtain automatically, if an endpoint returns an HTTP 401, a new API key for that user by calling the login endpoint? In this situation Postman loads the result and store the API key in a variable in the specific Environment.

Answer (score 0):

The test tab in Postman allows you to write some JS code that retrieves the response data and allows you to act accordingly.
Then the postman API allows you to set the next request in the collection runner or newman, so you can just call the login request properly.

Basically something like this:

```js
const jsonData = pm.response.json()

if (pm.response.code === 401) {
    pm.setNextRequest('login')
}
```

[Here is some further reading about scripting in postman](https://learning.postman.com/docs/writing-scripts/script-references/postman-sandbox-api-reference/#scripting-workflows).